# How do I detect or select the active camera in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I have an `a-image` entity.

When I set `look-at="[camera]"`, it does not point to the active camera.

When I set `look-at="#camera"` (which is the id of the active camera), it works just fine.

Does anyone know why it might not be working for `[camera]`? I have multiple cameras, but only one active at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[camera]` is a `querySelector` so when you do `[camera]` (which means any element with the camera attribute, which every camera has), you don’t have control of which camera will be selected.

If you’re switching between cameras and want to grab the active camera, you’d need to set a class or attribute on the active camera.

You can listen to the `camera-set-active` event:

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('camera-set-active', function (evt) {
  // 1. Remove active class from all cameras.
  // ...

  // 2. Add active class to camera.
  evt.detail.cameraEl.classList.add('active-camera');
});
```

For `look-at`, you can do `look-at=".active-camera"`. Unfortunately, since the component currently won't detect changes to class, you'll need to refresh it. Fastest way is to detach (`removeAttribute`) and re-attach the component (`setAttribute`).